# Leak/Address sanitizer in a shared library without LD_PRELOAD

Tags: shared-libraries, address-sanitizer, leak-sanitizer

I'm looking to use Clang's leak/address sanitizer on my shared library, which is loaded from JVM or `dotnet` (Linux) at runtime, so I can't recompile the binary.

Using `LD_PRELOAD` makes for a very noisy output, a lot (presumably false positive?) leaks get reported from the JVM itself. The sanitizer outright crashes when `LD_PRELOAD`ing for `dotnet`.

Is there any way to statically link the sanitizer into the shared library (or dynamically without `LD_PRELOAD`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing first, you can not statically link sanitizer runtime libs into your library. It has to be preloaded to intercept std allocator (`malloc`, etc.) and would malfunction otherwise (there's a special check at Asan startup that ensures that `libasan` was preloaded).

Noisy output in JVM may well be legitimate errors.
Using `LD_PRELOAD` makes for a very noisy output, a lot (presumably false positive?) leaks get reported from the JVM itself.

> The sanitizer outright crashes when `LD_PRELOAD`ing
>   for dotnet.

Is it a real crash or diagnosed memory error? Crash can be reported in [Asan tracker](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues).
Memory error should be reported to dotnet project but you can still continue execution after it using continue-after-error mode (grep for "continue-after-error" in [Asan FAQ](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer#faq)).

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping asan could only intercept calls to malloc() from my library (e.g. by linking with -Bsymbolic-functions) but not the main binary (I imagine it all ends up being forwarded to system malloc at some point?). I've raised a ticket for the crash.

Comment: @BłażejCzapp This will not work reliably in general case (because memory may be allocated in your library but deallocated elsewhere) so Asan works by intercepting allocator API globally. This is a design decision so not possible to alter easily.

Comment: Do you have some example of that? I though memory is never supposed to be deallocated 'elsewhere', precisely because different libraries may be using different allocation strategies? At least that seems to be common approach in C libraries, where you pass pointers back to the same library for deallocation.

Comment: @BłażejCzapp At least on Linux allocator (and it's heap) is coming from `libc.so.6` and is shared across all shared libraries in your application. Whoever deallocates the memory is an API detail (normally libraries prefer to deallocate themselves but this is not mandatory).

Comment: hi dear @yugr, I'm facing a similar issue as Blazej. There're so many leak errors coming out of libjvm.so, even though I'm using a very simple example project like https://github.com/dkelosky/java-jni. How can distinguish these "legitimate errors" from "actual errors in my C++ library" ? I'm trying to integrate ASAN into my CICD